# Does Fasttext use One Hot Encoding?

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, one-hot-encoding

In the original Skipgram/CBOW both context word and target word are represented as one-hot encoding.

Does fasttext also use one-hot encoding for each subword when training the skip-gram/CBOW model (so the length of the one-hot encoding vector is |Vocab| + |all subwords|)? If they use it, do they use it in both context and target words?

Comment: Have you looked at this document : https://towardsdatascience.com/fasttext-under-the-hood-11efc57b2b3 ?

Comment: I have read it, but I'm not quite sure with my understanding . The article mentions that the input vector size is  MAX_VOCAB + Bucket Size, is it the on-hot encoding vector?

Comment: The embedding part is implemented in Cpp. 
fasttext.cc and Vector.cc in https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/src . Tried to trace back. but no luck.

Comment: `getTargetCounts()` from the source code could hint, that it is counts and not binary one hot encoding. No mentioning of "context" in the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick answer would be **No**.

Let's walk through how FastText works internally:

For representation purposes, FastText internally initializes a dictionary. Dictionary contains all the collection of words. Besides words, it also maintains the count of all the words in the dictionary (and other information). Every time a new word is added to the dictionary its size is increased and `word2int_` is updated to `size_`(which is increased after assignment).

The code below adds a word into the dictionary.

```
// adding of new word
void Dictionary::add(const std::string& w) {
  int32_t h = find(w);
  ntokens_++;
  if (word2int_[h] == -1) {
    entry e;
    e.word = w;
    e.count = 1;
    e.type = getType(w);
    words_.push_back(e);
    word2int_[h] = size_++; //  word2int_[h] is assigned a uniuqe value 
  } else {
    words_[word2int_[h]].count++; // word's count is being updated here
  }
}

// funciton used to access word ID (which is the representation used)
int32_t Dictionary::getId(const std::string& w) const {
  int32_t h = find(w);
  return word2int_[h];
}
```

As mentioned in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/fasttext-under-the-hood-11efc57b2b3) medium article, `word2int_` is indexed on the hash of the word string, and stores a sequential int index to the `words_` array. The maximum size of `word2int_` vector can be `30000000`.

For embeddings matrix of `M x N` is created where `M = MAX_VOCAB_SIZE + bucket_size`. Where, `M` is total vocabulary size including `bucket_size` corresponds to the total size of array allocated for all the n-gram tokens and `N` is the dimension of the embedding vector, which means the representation for one word requires the size of 1.

The code below shows how to compute the hash and calculates the ID of the subword. A similar logic is used to access the subword vector. Note here `h` is an integer value which is calculated using `dict_->hash()`. This function returns the same `h` value which is used when adding a word in the dictionary. This makes the process of accessing word IDs only dependent on the value of `h`.

```
int32_t FastText::getSubwordId(const std::string& subword) const {
  int32_t h = dict_->hash(subword) % args_->bucket;
  return dict_->nwords() + h;
}

void FastText::getSubwordVector(Vector& vec, const std::string& subword) const {
  vec.zero();
  int32_t h = dict_->hash(subword) % args_->bucket;
  h = h + dict_->nwords();
  addInputVector(vec, h);
}
```

Long story short, FastText makes use of integer IDs assigned at the beginning and use those IDs to access the embeddings.

I hope this helps. All the code samples are taken from [FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/) repo. Feel free to dive in to understand more.

Comment: This is really cool, thank you for this @vikas!

Comment: great explanation, thank you!

Comment: I am glad it was helpful! @malioboro

Comment: You are welcome! @NischalHp